# "Private" name mangling and instance vs class attributes

Tags: python, attributes, private-members, name-mangling

I was writing a decorator that needs to access private variables and found this discrepancy. Can anyone explain this?

(Python 2.5)

Naming mangling works as expected for attributes defined in the class:

```
>>> class Tester(object):
...    __foo = "hi"

>>> t = Tester()
>>> t._Tester__foo
'hi'
```

Instance attributes do not work (and this is the way we are supposed to do it right?)

```
>>> class Tester(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.__foo = "hi"

>>> t = Tester()
>>> t._Tester__foo
AttributeError: 'Tester' object has no attribute '_Tester__foo'
```

P.S. Is "class attribute" the right word for these? They aren't static, but if you make one of those a list, or some other mutable type, it is shared...

**Update**

In fact, second example works fine, too. It was a hardware issue (restart helped).

Comment: Class attribute is the right word. And they are *always* shared. Mutability does not matter. It pretty much never matters, except when asking if you can mutate a given object.

Comment: Can I nuke this question? Or does anyone see value in keeping it? I can't reproduce my original issue. It seems to work as expected.

Comment: Rather leave it around, since @MartijnPieters went all the way on testing the issue in a lot of Python testings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is actually *not* correct.

Name mangling takes place at class creation time; any functions that refer to mangled names are adjusted as well.

I cannot reproduce your example, at least not in Python versions 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 3.1 and 3.2 on the Mac:

```
>>> class Tester(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.__foo = "hi"
... 
>>> Tester()._Tester__foo
'hi'
>>> Tester().__foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Tester' object has no attribute '__foo'
```

If you disassemble the function bytecode you can see the name has been mangled as well:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(Tester.__init__)
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('hi')
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              6 STORE_ATTR               1 (_Tester__foo)
              9 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

I've checked the [compiler source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Python/compile.c) and *all* names are run through the mangler, a code path that has remained the same since  2002 at least.

And yes, class attributes and instance attributes are the correct terms. Class attributes are always shared, but assignment *to* an attribute on an instance assigns to the instance. Mutating a list or other mutable objects is not the same as attribute assignment.

Comment: You are right. I have no idea what happened there. I happen to restart my computer, so I'll just have to call it an IT issue, "Have you tried turning it off and on again?" ;)